# Last list exported - most recent list

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a function which enables me extract the date of the most recent csv file created within a specific directory (mydomian.com/csv_bakup/) Here is the code ....

```
public function get_last_list_exported(){
      $date_str_arr = array();

      // timestamp of last csv file ?
      exec('ls -ltr mydomian.com/csv_bakup/ | tail -1',$output);
      $temp_a = explode(' ', $output[0]);      
      $date_str_arr = explode('_', $temp_a[9]); 
      return $date_str_arr[0].'/'.$date_str_arr[1].'/20'.$date_str_arr[2];
}
```

The function makes use of the php exec() function to run a linux command.

All works well locally but when I migrate it to the live server it errors about `undefined offsets` in the line

```
return $date_str_arr[0].'/'.$date_str_arr[1].'/20'.$date_str_arr[2];
```

Running linux commands like this seem to be the simplest solution ...

Are there better, though simpler, solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I imagine is going on:

`undefined offset` means you're referring to an array key that doesn't exist, which implies the array is empty, which implies that `$output` was empty, which implies that the execution of the command failed.

First possible reason: is your path definitely correct?

Second: It's probably because your server doesn't allow shell access/only provides very limited shell access.  Check your `php.ini` for disabled commands and read http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir.

Test the first one by running a simple command in `exec()` and `var_dump()`ing the raw output.  Did you get anything?

Also, accept your answers if they're helpful as the previous commenters have said.